# Imagens com uri vindo da API React Native

Tags: api, react-native, path, image, uri

No banco de dados eu guardo o path da imagem junto com as outras informações da postagem, ai na pagina que quero que apareça as imagem uso um flatlist listando as postagem e mostrando a sua imagem se esse post tiver:

**Flatlist mostrando as postagem que tem no banco de dados**

```
<FlatList
      data={postList}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
          return(
            
            
            
            <View style={styles.postagemRed}>
              
                <View style={styles.postCima}>
                  

                  <Text style={styles.iconPost}></Text>
                  <View style={styles.separador}>
                    <View style={styles.nomeDate}>
                      <Text style={styles.postText}>{item.nome}</Text>
                      <Text style={[styles.postText, styles.dateText]}>
                        { // tratamento da variável de data
                          item.data.substring(8,10)+'/'+ // dia
                          item.data.substring(5,7) +'/'+ // mes
                          item.data.substring(0,4)       // ano
                        }   
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <Text style={[styles.postText, styles.cargoText]} >{item.identificacao}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </View>
              
                
                
                
                {item.nomeImage &&

                    //por algum motivo a imagem não aparece
                    <Image style={styles.imagePost}  source={{uri : item.path}} />
                  }
                  
                  
                  


                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.postBaixo}
                underlayColor='#FFFFFF00'
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('OpenPost', {idPost : item.id })}>
                  <View>


                    <Text numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode={'tail'} style={styles.tituloText}>{item.titulo}</Text>
                    <Text style={[styles.tituloText, styles.temaTexto]} >{item.tema}</Text>
                  
    
                    <View style={styles.corpoPost}>
                      <Text numberOfLines={3} ellipsizeMode={'tail'} style={styles.postTexto}>
                      {item.texto}
                      </Text>
                    </View>              
                  </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
              

          </View>


          );
        }}
        />
```

**Parte dentro do flatlist que faz a comparação se o post tem imagem e deveria mostrar a imagem (mas aparece so o espaço da imagem no pagina sem nada)**

```
{item.nomeImage &&
<Image style={styles.imagePost}  source={{uri : item.path}} />
}
```

se eu der um console log nesse "item.path" ele retorna o caminho certo da imagem e se usar um

```
{item.nomeImage &&
<Image style={styles.imagePost}  source={require("caminho que ta na variavel 'item.path'")} />
}
```

ele mostra a imagem

exemplo de valor do item.path:

*../../img/postagemPhoto/postagemPicture1628191387071.jpg*

obs: como faço pra redimensionar a imagem original pro tamanho dessa tag image, desse jeito que ta so mostra a parte central da imagem.

Answer (score 0):

Olá

Acredito que o `resizeMode` resolva seu problema, as opções aceitas são: **cover, contain, stretch, repeat, center**.

O valor padrão é: **cover**